# image moves text in HTML

Tags: html, text

I am making a webpage with an image below a button, with a link next to it. When I added the image, the button and link shifted next to the image, I want them to stay above it. This is my code:

```
<div class="jumbotron-inner text-center">

    <h2>Random Text</h2>

    <a href"#"  class="btn btn-info btn-large">Button</a>
    <a href"#">Link</a>

    <img src="img/image.png" alt="" />




</div>
```

Comment: This must be because you have not defined any width for the container 'jumbotron-inner', or else you can simply use `<br />`

Comment: thank you for correcting my question but there is a button and a link. (a href="#") I meant to have my "grammar" like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="jumbotron-inner text-center">

    <h2>Random Text</h2>
    <div>
    <a href"#"  class="btn btn-info btn-large">Button</a>
    <a href"#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="img/image.png" alt="" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Now it should work as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also using css-

```
a {
    display:block;
}
```